# Change open graph type

Tags: types, facebook-opengraph

I specify "video" as the og type at the root of my blog, then realize my mistake and try to change it to "blog". Yet, I read that this is not possible at any cost because the blog has been liked or shared.

Seriously???

If these classifications are to mean anything at all, not allowing a change would be the brightest(!) idea EVER anyone could come up with.

So again... Is this the case? If so, what happens if I ignore the "Errors must be fixed" warning? Does FB continue tagging my blog as a video or mess up something else instead?

I searched for a solution but all I could find was equally frustrated questions.

Thanks in advance for your clarification!

Comment: What does the [Open Graph debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) say about your blog?

Comment: The object at 'http://example.com/' previously had type 'video' and cannot be changed to an object of type 'website' to avoid data corruption of existing actions.